# Will the US resident be taxed or need to declare amount of a Canadian Cash gift of approx $20,000 USD?

Tags: taxes, inheritance

Mom living in Canada wants to give child living in US $25,000 CAD (approx $19,800 USD).  Canada doesn't have tax to pay on gifts.  Will the US resident be taxed or need to declare the amount?

Answer (score 2):

If your mother is not a US citizen, and the gift is "only" $20K, it seems that you do not need to tell the IRS.

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/gifts-from-foreign-person

> If you are a U.S. person (...) who received large gifts or bequests from a foreign person, you may need to complete Part IV of Form 3520, Annual Return to Report Transactions with Foreign Trusts and Receipt of Certain Foreign Gifts, and file the form by the 15th day of the fourth month following the end of your income tax year (generally, April 15th for individuals), subject to any extension of time to file that may apply.

> You are required to report the receipt of foreign gifts or bequests only if the applicable thresholds apply.  For purposes of determining the reporting thresholds, you must aggregate gifts received from related parties.  See the instructions to Part IV of Form 3520 for more information; see also Section VI of Notice 97-34 PDF.

> **For gifts or bequests from a nonresident alien or foreign estate**, you are required to report the receipt of such gifts or bequests **only if the aggregate amount received from that nonresident alien** or foreign estate **exceeds $100,000 during the taxable year**.  If the gifts or bequests exceed $100,000, you must separately identify each gift in excess of $5,000.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just do not want to be responsible for paying tax to the US on a Canadian cash gift. If so my mom could send a portion this year and a portion next year.  There are wire transfer fees to send and receive each time though that we would like to avoid paying extra fees.  I cannot get ahold of the IRS to ask this question.

Comment: In my search I have seen also something about a $15,000 limit per year.  So it gets confusing.

Comment: @Mandy the $15K limit is for what U.S. tax persons give each other.  Is your mother an American living in Canada?

Comment: No my mother is a Canadian who lives in Canada. I am a Canadian but also a legal permanent resident of the US and have lived here for 17 years.

Comment: @Mandy it appears that you can receive gifts from "foreigners in foreign countries" totaling $100K/year without telling the IRS.

Comment: Ok great thanks so much! Appreciate your time. Do you know the cheapest and safest way to send the $$ by chance?

Comment: @Mandy Cheapest?  Nope.  The bank would know the safest; probably some sort of wire.  (Lots of people must transfer money between CA & US every day...)

Comment: @Mandy regarding your unrelated question, everyone just uses OFX.com (or competitors such as transferwise) to send largish amounts of money around at the best rate.  regarding the can/usd pair your bank won't rip you off, but you'll save a few bucks w/ ofx

Comment: Ok wonderful.  Thanks to both of you for your help! :)